# SQL Server 2008 R2, Function POWER different results in SQL SERVER compared to Oracle, calculator HP 12c and Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, function, math

I Have a math problem, in Oracle we use this expression

```
SELECT ROUND(POWER(1.1413, (1.0/252.0)),9) FROM DUAL;
```

This query return 1,000524614. In HP and Excel we had the same results.

In SQL Server

```
DECLARE @x FLOAT = 1.1413, @Y FLOAT = (1.0/252.0);
SELECT ROUND(POWER(@x, @Y), 9), @X, @Y;
This Query return 1,00052458.
```

I need the results in the two databases to be identical.
If it is a problem that can not be fixed or circumvented, is there any other way out of these calculations inside the Sql Server?
Is there any way to use a c language or c ++ api math.h within Sql Server?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `float` is by default 4 bytes in SQL Server rather than 8.  It needs a precision argument.  (See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx).)

This produces the "correct" answer:

```
select round(power(convert(float(53), 1.413), 1.0 / convert(float(53), 252.0)), 9);
```

Your code might work if you change the declarations:

```
DECLARE @x FLOAT(53) = 1.1413, @Y FLOAT(53) = 1.0/252.0;

SELECT ROUND(POWER(@x, @Y), 9), @X, @Y;
```

However, you might need to do the conversion before the division for `@Y`.

Comment: For minimum changes to the code, casting at least the 1.0 to float(53) will force @Y to 8 bytes and will produce the required result.

Answer (score 0):

In my procedure I have many accounts that use this structure, I had to do something like this:

Before:
SELECT ROUND (POWER (14.13 / 100.0 + 1.0, 1.0 / 252.0) - 1.0,8) FATOR_DIA;

After:
DECLARE @ VALUE FLOAT = 14.13, @CEM FLOAT (53) = 100, @HUM FLOAT (53) = 1, @ D252 FLOAT (53) = 252;
SELECT ROUND (POWER (@ VALUE / @CEM + @HUM, @HUM / @ D252) - @ HUM, 8) FACTOR_DIA;

This fix corrected the problem.
Thanks for the answer.